# Display an image at the click of a button in thymeleaf java

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I want to display an image in the browser from a click of a button.

In my view, I loop over a list that returns to me my controller. For each element of the list I would like to be able to display the image associated with the element. The images are in a folder placed at the root it is in the resources folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxfRy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcIc3.png)

Comment: Please consider writing your part of the code as a text instead of attached image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`<img>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) inside `th:each`.

```
<img th:src="@{'/photos/' + ${vehicules.image}}"/>
```